# Disable certain cxRadioButtons inside a dxCheckGroupBox

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have a `dxCheckGroupBox` with 5 `cxRadioButtons` inside.
Check box of the `dxCheckGroupBox` toggles it's state (`cbaToggleChildrenEnabledState`) from enabled to disabled.

How can I disable certain `cxRadioButtons` inside `dxCheckGroupBox` so they stay
disabled when I click the `dxCheckGroupBox`'s check box ?

I tried disabling the buttons by code in the `OnFormShow` event but it does not work.
As soon as I click `dxCheckGroupBox`'s check box they all get enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `CheckAction` property of the `dxCheckGroupBox`;

```
dxCheckGroupBox1.CheckBox.CheckAction := cbaNone;
```

You'll be able to disable/enable controls.